# How would I use sliders to manipulate the slope and intercept of a plane in a graphics 3d box while the cdf was running

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, slider

Would I link a slider value to a polynomial that represents the plane and draw it in the draw plane a function,

Or, is there a way that would allow me to have sliders in the draw plane function itself.

What I want to do, Is have an image of a sloped 3d plane that a can move with sliders, I want to be able to adjust the amount of slope that the plane has, the height of it, and finaly, maybe rotate it.

I want to get the value of these sliders after I have the shape of the plane that I wanted, and then use these values to calculate a "would be" sum of squares.

So something like this, how exactly would I have the plane move as I adjusted the sliders, so for example a slider labeled intercept would raise or lower the intercept of the plane.

```
x0 := -2;
y0 := 1;
z0 := 3;

Manipulate[F[x_, y_] := (a+slidera x0 + b+slider b y0 + c+slider b z0 - a x - b y)/c;

Plot3D[F[x, y], {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 10}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]]
```

Comment: At the moment your question seems to be too broad amd somewhat unclear,  please clarify.  It would also be good to show previous efforts/code.

Comment: You might start by drawing a single plane with `Plot3D`.  From there you can identify, in your function, the parameters that you would like to vary.  Each can then be associated with a slider.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like:

```
f[a_, b_, c_][x_, y_] := a + {b, c}.{x, y};
disp = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}};

Manipulate[With[{p1 = {px, py, f[a, b, c][px, py]}, p0 = {px, py, pz}},
   Show[ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, f[a, b, c][x, y]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
    MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, Mesh -> {{px}, {py}},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[{Blue, Opacity[.7]}], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
    BoxRatios -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], 
   Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{p0, p1}, .3], Opacity[.5], Pink, 
     Polygon[{p0, p1, {p1[[1]], p1[[2]] + Abs[p1[[3]] - pz], p1[[3]]},
       {p1[[1]], p1[[2]] + Abs[p1[[3]] - pz], pz}}],
     Polygon[{px, py, -10} + Abs[(pz - p1[[3]])/2] # & /@ disp], 
     Opacity[1], Black, Text[Style[Round[(p1[[3]] - pz)^2, .01], 14, Bold], {px, py, -10}]}], 
   Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Squared Error = "<>ToString@Round[(p1[[3]] -pz)^2, .01], 20, "Panel"]]],
 Grid[{{Style["Point Coordinates", 16, "Panel"], Spacer[5], Style["Parameters", 16, "Panel"]}, 
    {Control@{{px, -2}, -10, 10}, Spacer[5], Control@{{a, 0}, 0, 5}}, 
    {Control@{{py, 1}, -10, 10},  Spacer[5], Control@{{b, 0}, -1, 1}},
    {Control@{{pz, 5}, -10, 10},  Spacer[5], Control@{{c, 0}, -1, 1}}}],
 Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

[image]